# Best joint for pine storm windows? Mostly why not miters?

Tags: windows, joints

I'm going to make storm windows. 1x3 select pine. Every online discussion I've seen refers to mortise and tenons, lap joint, or a doweled butt joint. I haven't seen any do a 45 joint like a picture frame.

Why is this?

I like the 45s because I can run the rabbets for the glass along the full length of each board before cutting. If strength is an issue I can use biscuits or pocket screws. So - any downside to the 45s?

Answer (score 6):

In a miter joint you're gluing end grain to end grain. That's inherently weaker than most joints.

If you really want this appearance, at least spline the corners so there's significant long-grain gluing area. A mitered half-lap would be another possibility, or one of the other joints that mimics a miter in appearance but has something stronger underneath it.